# How to use Store procedure in entity frame work

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have created store procedure in Sql server its working.when i imliment it into my entity framework, its throws exception, I am new to this, kindly suggest

```
   //SQL//
create procedure sp_getUserID
@deviceID  int,
@userID int out
as
Begin
Select @userID= userId from UserTable
where deviceID = @deviceID
End



   // C#
   var UserID =0; 
// This line error  ERROR:  //The specified parameter name '@userID' is not valid.
  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter UserOutput = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("@userID", typeof(int));

var objStoredProcd = dbContext.sp_getUserID(UserOutput, UserLogin.DeviceUUID);
   UserID = Convert.ToInt32(UserOutput.Value);
```

Comment: Remove the `@`.

Comment: @thanks it work for me